# pause, resume, abort and resolve of long running promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

My controller is able to pause, resume and resolve a long-running promise.
When my controller aborts the Promise, somehow my controller recursion loop is broken.

I learned about Promise a few days ago, so maybe I don't understand something about reject or catch.

First of all, a state variable that can be checked in between steps of the promise chain.

```
var state = "idle"
```

A shim promise that can be inserted to check this state variable

```
// insert this shim before each link of promise chain
function promise_to_check_pause_and_abort(x) {
    if (state == "running") {
        return Promise.resolve(x) // just keep going 
    } else if (state == "pause") {
        let P = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let resume_cb = () => { resolve() }
            pause_cb_queue.push(resume_cb)
        });
        return P;
    } else if (state == "abort") {
        return Promise.reject("aborted at stage " + x)
    } else {
        return promise.reject("should not be executing in this invalid state = " + state)
    }
}
```

My real application runs many chained promises that can take 15+ minutes to complete.  This is not needed to demonstrate my problem. So here is a simple fake task that returns a promise.

```
function promise_to_do_something_long_running(n) {
    if (isNaN(n)) {
        n = 0;
    }

    if (n == 100) {
        return Promise.resolve("done")

    } else {
        let P = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("doing " + n);
                resolve();
            }, 100)
        })

        return P
            .then(() => { return promise_to_check_pause_and_abort(n) })
            .then(() => { return promise_to_do_something_long_running(n + 1) })
    }

}
```

Now a simple text controller to start, pause, resume, and abort the above long-running promise.

```
// A recursive controller. 
//   Get response based on current running state.
//   Regardless of response, do it again.
function controller() {

    if (state == "running") {
        rl.question("abort or pause :", (answer) => {

            if (answer == "abort") {
                state = "abort"
            } else if (answer == "pause") {
                state = "pause"
            };

            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })

    } else if (state == "pause") {
        rl.question("abort or resume :", (answer) => {

            if (answer == "abort") {
                state = "abort";
                pause_cb_queue.forEach((cb) => { cb() })
                pause_cb_queue = []
            } else if (answer == "resume") {
                state = "running"
                pause_cb_queue.forEach((cb) => { cb() })
                pause_cb_queue = []
            };

            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })

    } else if (state == "idle") {

        rl.question("start :", (answer) => {

            if (answer == "start") {
                state = "running";

                // controller loop not dependent on resolution of this
                // only state is 
                promise_to_do_something_long_running()
                    .then((a) => {
                        console.log("completed task, response :" + a);
                        state = "idle"
                    })
                    .catch((b) => {
                        console.log("task rejected with response :" + b);
                        state = "idle"
                    });
            };

            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })
    }

}


controller();
```

**Everything works perfect, except when I abort, the controller recursion breaks and no more input is solicited from the user.  How can execution of the**

```
.catch((b) => {
                        console.log("task rejected with response :" + b);
                        state = "idle"
                    });
```

**cause the outer controller recursion to stop?**

The complete code that runs in nodejs is as follows:

```
'use strict';


const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var state = "idle"
var pause_cb_queue = []


// insert this shim before each link of promise chain
function promise_to_check_pause_and_abort(x) {
    if (state == "running") {
        return Promise.resolve(x) // just keep going 
    } else if (state == "pause") {
        let P = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let resume_cb = () => { resolve() }
            pause_cb_queue.push(resume_cb)
        });
        return P;
    } else if (state == "abort") {
        return Promise.reject("aborted at stage " + x)
    } else {
        return promise.reject("should not be executing in this invalid state = " + state)
    }
}

function promise_to_do_something_long_running(n) {
    if (isNaN(n)) {
        n = 0;
    }

    if (n == 100) {
        return Promise.resolve("done")

    } else {
        let P = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("doing " + n);
                resolve();
            }, 100)
        })

        return P
            .then(() => { return promise_to_check_pause_and_abort(n) })
            .then(() => { return promise_to_do_something_long_running(n + 1) })
    }

}

// A recursive controller. 
//   Get response based on current running state.
//   Regardless of response, do it again.
function controller() {

    if (state == "running") {
        rl.question("abort or pause :", (answer) => {

            if (answer == "abort") {
                state = "abort"
            } else if (answer == "pause") {
                state = "pause"
            };

            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })

    } else if (state == "pause") {
        rl.question("abort or resume :", (answer) => {

            if (answer == "abort") {
                state = "abort";
                pause_cb_queue.forEach((cb) => { cb() })
                pause_cb_queue = []
            } else if (answer == "resume") {
                state = "running"
                pause_cb_queue.forEach((cb) => { cb() })
                pause_cb_queue = []
            };

            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })

    } else if (state == "idle") {

        rl.question("start :", (answer) => {

            if (answer == "start") {
                state = "running";

                // controller loop not dependent on resolution of this
                // only state is 
                promise_to_do_something_long_running()
                    .then((a) => {
                        console.log("completed task, response :" + a);
                        state = "idle"
                    })
                    .catch((b) => {
                        console.log("task rejected with response :" + b);
                        state = "idle"
                    });
            };

            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })
    }

}


controller();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with pausing and resuming promises.  My bug was missing handling the abort state in the controller.

```
    } else if (state == "abort") {
        rl.question("in abort state, no valid input :", (answer) => {
            controller(); // regardless of response or state, get input again
        })
```

with the above addition, everything works perfectly.  I can now suspend promise chains.